# How can I solve those problems with the command npm run android in react native expo

Tags: react-native, gradle, build.gradle

I just created that project using npx create-expo-app ecaver --template, and choosing the blank (Blare) option to have access to the native code, when I try to run npx expo start it works well, but when I try to run npm run android to run the app without expo go, I got those two problems here:

```
> Configure project :expo-modules-core
[CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\santo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620 did not have a source.properties file
[CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\santo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620 did not have a source.properties file

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\santo\OneDrive\Documentos\Geobyte\e-caver\node_modules\expo-modules-autolinking\scripts\android\autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 273

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-modules-core'.       
   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
      > org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: NDK is not installed      > Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
5 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 3 up-to-date
Error: C:\Users\santo\OneDrive\Documentos\Geobyte\e-caver\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: C:\Users\santo\OneDrive\Documentos\Geobyte\e-caver\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\santo\OneDrive\Documentos\Geobyte\e-caver\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:472:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\santo\OneDrive\Documentos\Geobyte\e-caver\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\santo\OneDrive\Documentos\Geobyte\e-caver\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\santo\OneDrive\Documentos\Geobyte\e-caver\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
    at Object.assembleAsync (C:\Users\santo\OneDrive\Documentos\Geobyte\e-caver\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)
    at runAndroidAsync (C:\Users\santo\OneDrive\Documentos\Geobyte\e-caver\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:31:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I do not know if its related but in the tab erros I got those too:

```
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

android/app
unable to resolve class com.android.build.OutputFile
 @ line 4, column 8.
```

How can I fix it?